# Linear Regression Excel Question

Tags: regression, excel

Let's say I am comparing the impact on features for a housing market. If I were to take the data for all houses in a region with a value between USD 200,000 and USD 500,000 and compare how individual feature differences (e.g. Bathroom Count, Square feet, etc.) affect their price, how would I accurately portray these impacts? I get that if I did a simple linear regression, or something similar, that I would be able to see the impact of that one variable on the price, but wouldn't this be misleading if there are other variables at play?

For example, would there be a way in Microsoft Excel to compare the Price of a house against both its Bathroom count and Gross SQFT differences at the same time? Would a simple Multiple Regression be enough, or would some sort of outlier removal be necessary/doable?
Also, would there be an easy way to tell how much each variable impacted the price from there?

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note that dollar symbols here indicate TeX-like markup for showing mathematical notation. Currency in US or other dollars can be indicated by escaping the dollar symbol or by a direct name or abbreviation, as above.

Comment: I would largely avoid doing anything related to statistics in Excel. Better programs would include R or Jamovi.

Answer (score 2):

> I get that if I did a simple linear regression, or something similar, that I would be able to see the impact of that one variable on the price, but wouldn't this be misleading if there are other variables at play?

It is true that the coefficients from a linear model represent the "ceteris paribus" effect -- that is to say, the associated effect on the expected outcome while holding all other variables constant.  That being said, we can still determine the total effect against some reference class.  Let's see an example.

I will do all my computations in R because while excel is popular it isn't a very good tool for reproducing statistical computations.  I'll use the [`house`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/liver/html/house.html) data from the `{liver}` package for this demonstration.

First, let's fit a linear model

```
library(tidyverse)

data('house', package = 'liver')

fit <- lm(unit.price ~ house.age + stores.number, data=house)
```

We can examine the coefficients to determine the ceteris paribus effect of each variable.

```r
> summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = unit.price ~ house.age + stores.number, data = house)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-36.345  -7.116  -2.010   5.475  85.874 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   32.02251    1.19529  26.791  < 2e-16 ***
house.age     -0.28601    0.04632  -6.174  1.6e-09 ***
stores.number  2.69251    0.17916  15.028  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.71 on 411 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3833,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3803 
F-statistic: 127.7 on 2 and 411 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

When the age of the house is 0 and there are no convenience stores around, then all houses are predicted to have the same unit price.  You can verify this easily in R

```r
library(tidyverse)

data('house', package = 'liver')

fit <- lm(unit.price ~ house.age + stores.number, data=house)

house %>% 
filter(house.age==0, stores.number==0) %>% 
modelr::add_predictions(fit) %>% 
select(house.age, stores.number, pred)

#>   house.age stores.number     pred
#> 1         0             0 32.02251
#> 2         0             0 32.02251
#> 3         0             0 32.02251
#> 4         0             0 32.02251
#> 5         0             0 32.02251
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now, let's consider how the predicted price might change when we change the house age *and* the number of stores from 0 to 1.  To your point, two things are changing at the same time, but since the model is linear in the parameters, then we can still explain why the prediction changes in the way it does.

The model is

$$ y = 32.02 -0.29 \times \text{age} + 2.70 \times \text{stores} $$

If we increase the stores from 0 to 1 and the age from 0 to 1, then the prediction for one year old houses with one store should be

$$ 32.02 -0.29  + 2.70 =  34.43 $$

We can verify this is true

````
``` r
library(tidyverse)

data('house', package = 'liver')

fit <- lm(unit.price ~ house.age + stores.number, data=house)

tibble(house.age = 1, stores.number=1) %>% 
  modelr::add_predictions(fit)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   house.age stores.number  pred
#>       <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1         1             1  34.4
````

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So assuming the model is a good one, the coefficients from a linear model are all you need to determine how the price changes as all the other variables change.  Things get more complex as the model becomes more complex, but this looks like a good place to stop.  If you add more information to your question, I can add more detail as needed.